# DTO entity tests using Json Test do not pass

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to test my DTO classes using the @JsonTest annotation, but the tests fail with an error
Description:

A component required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'itemRepository' defined in ru.practicum.shareit.item.Repository.ItemRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on

Entities do not contain complex objects and interactions with the database

```
package ru.practicum.shareit.user;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.json.JsonTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.json.JacksonTester;
import org.springframework.boot.test.json.JsonContent;
import ru.practicum.shareit.item.Repository.ItemRepository;
import ru.practicum.shareit.user.dto.UserDto;
import ru.practicum.shareit.user.userStorage.UserRepository;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

@JsonTest
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class UserDtoTest {
    @Autowired
    private JacksonTester<UserDto> json;

    @Test
    public void testUserDto() throws Exception {
        UserDto userDto = new UserDto(
                1l,
                "name",
                "email@ya.ru"
        );
        JsonContent<UserDto> result = json.write(userDto);
        assertThat(result).extractingJsonPathNumberValue("$.id").isEqualTo(1);
        assertThat(result).extractingJsonPathStringValue("$.name").isEqualTo("name");
        assertThat(result).extractingJsonPathStringValue("$.email").isEqualTo("email@ya.ru");
    }
}
```

Comment: @Autowired requires the spring context, so the test is probably trying to load the entire context which is failing.  Try creating a `JacksonTester<UserDto>` manually in a @BeforeEach or as part of the @Test.  Side note: there doesn't appear to be much value to this test since the code tests a third party library (which presumably has its own tests).

Comment: Look like a issue in item repo